# Postgresql - ORDER BY DESC is not working

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I have a sql query like this.

```
select
SUM(balance.amount) as amount
from "provider_games"
left join "balance" on "balance"."game_id" = "provider_games"."game_id"
group by "provider_games"."game_id"
order by "amount" desc limit 5
```

My balance table includes:

```
game_id | amount
245 - 146.00
244 - 5013.00
```

When I make "order by desc", the result is incorrect:

```
amount
null
null
null
null
null
```

Comment: There is data in the provider_games and balance tables.

Comment: thank you very much dude. the code you wrote worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`order by ... desc` sorts NULL values to the top. And as you limit the result to 5 rows, you only see the NULL values.

One way to work around that is to make Postgres sort the NULL values to the end:

```
order by amount desc nulls last
limit 5
```

---

As you are apparently not interested in NULL values, you can also change your outer join into an inner join, then you are most likely not getting any NULL values at all.